# History plugin question

Tags: history, full-node

I just installed Jungle Testnet node with an automatic script. There is a history plugin enabled by default. But now I read it has been deprecated.

Is there any replacement with the same API `getActions`? We finished a Java implementation of `getActions` just recently.

The goal is to get the last 20 tx for a particular account and also get tx by tx id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hyperion has a v1 history compatible api.  Hyperion stores data in elastic search.  https://hyperion.docs.eosrio.io/

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an EOS node, you can call cleos to get last actions. For example:

```
cleos -u https://eos.greymass.com get actions <account> -1 -20 -j
```

to get last 20 transactions for a given account.

Comment: Yes, that would work for console. For this you don't need whole EOS node (nodeos), just cleos would do. This is not for Java and we need our node with specific plugins. So the answer is not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

CryptoLions, the bp of EOS, made EOS-mongo-history-API which aims at providing similar APIs to history plugin with mongoDB. You can find the implementation from [here](https://github.com/CryptoLions/EOS-mongo-history-API).

`state-history-plugin` is in progress to change the way to find data from blocks, but it might be a little different from the way that history_plugin provided.

Comment: I know about these already, but thanks. Question was for 1:1 compatible API. Guess nobody develop modular API anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have found something like this: 
https://github.com/acoutts/EOS-state-history-API

But I am not sure that it truly works because I haven't tested the plugin. :)

Comment: looks like is ok because of this: https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.7.0/docs/monitoring-with-3rd-party

Answer (score 0):

History data will become a business for block producers and other third-party history providers. When I asked Dan Larimer about this he answered by asking a question -- does your bank provide free access to all your banking data? In other words, he is hinting that historical data is expensive to maintain and historical data will be a service that you can pay to access. It makes sense to charge for history data if someone is trying to get data that does not belong to their account.

I believe the future will go towards a EOS "client" browser that we run as an individual account holder and store our own transactions data on our own computers and/or decentralize it at our own expense to other providers.

Own and Safeguard Your Blockchain Data at Your Cost -- seems to be the motto.